# write to a wav file while streaming node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, socket.io

Is there a way to force .pipe on a stream to write to a file every certain time/size?

Basically, I am using socket io stream, from a browser I am sending a buffer with audio and I send with emit:

**Browser**

```
        c.onaudioprocess = function(o) 
        {
        var input = o.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

            stream1.write( new ss.Buffer( convertFloat32ToInt16( input ) ));

        }
```

**Server (nodejs)**

```
var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter('/tmp/demo.wav', {
    channels: 1,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    bitDepth: 16
});

ss(socket).on('client-stream-request', function(stream)
{
    stream.pipe(fileWriter);
}
```

The problem I have is that the file demo.wav will be only wrote when I finish the stream, so when I stop the microphone. But I would like it to write always, as I will be doing speech recognition using google, any ideas? If I call the speech recognition from google using pipe, the chuncks are too small and google is not able to recognize it.

Comment: hi @peterpeterson, did you make it work? I think I'm following the same tutorial as you, but would like to use socket instead of binaryjs, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the Node [stream API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) it looks like you should be able to add an options parameter to the pipe function.
Try

```
stream.pipe(fileWriter, { end: false });
```

Comment: That will not save the file, in fact by default is true, which is what I want but because I am always streaming it will only write when I finish the streaming but I want to save part of the stream, so for example every 1mb write into a new file, or every 1 minute write to another file, etc..

Comment: You can try ending the stream manually `fileWriter.end()` using setTimeout.